# Anyway I can shorten this IF statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want the program to only print the 9 digit numbers that obey all the rules set by the IF statement. However, I feel like it is unnecessarily long and I would love it if someone could show me some syntax that would shorten it. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I need to figure out every single different combination of a 3x3 grid  using only numbers 1,2 & 3. However, 1, 2 & 3 can only go in a single row ONCE and also go in a single column ONCE.
N.b. I think there are 12 different combinations.

```
public static void main (String [] args){



    int count =0;

    for (int i=111111111; i<1000000000; i++){



        int X=i;
        String x= String.valueOf(X);
        String a1= x.substring(0,1);
        String a2= x.substring(1,2);
        String a3= x.substring(2,3);
        String b1= x.substring(3,4);
        String b2= x.substring(4,5);
        String b3= x.substring(5,6);
        String c1= x.substring(6, 7);
        String c2= x.substring(7,8);
        String c3= x.substring(8,9);

        int A1= Integer.parseInt(a1); 
        int A2= Integer.parseInt(a2);
        int A3= Integer.parseInt(a3);
        int B1= Integer.parseInt(b1);
        int B2= Integer.parseInt(b2);
        int B3= Integer.parseInt(b3);
        int C1= Integer.parseInt(c1); 
        int C2= Integer.parseInt(c2);
        int C3= Integer.parseInt(c3);

        if (A1+B1+C1+A2+B2+C2+A3+B3+C3==18 
            && A1<=3 && A2<=3 && A3<=3 && B1<=3 && B2<=3 && B3<=3 && C1<=3 && C2<=3 && C3<=3 
            && A1+B1+C1==6 && A1+A2+A3==6 
            && A1!=B1 && B1!=C1 && A1!=C1 && A1!=A2 && A2!=A3 && A1!=A3 && C1!=C2 && C2!=C3 
            && C1!=C3 && B1!= B2 && B1!=B3 && B2!=B3 && A3!=B3 && A2!=B2 && A3!=C3 && A2!=C2 
            && B2!=C2) 
        {             

                count++;                                                                                                        
                    System.out.println(count);
                    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I think this code has lots more problems than this if test.

Comment: Ugly, magic numbers, unclear, obtuse.  Shall I go on?

Comment: write a method that determines whether or not `x` is valid

Comment: why all of the `<= 3` stuff? `x <= 333333333` would do just as well

Comment: Sure.  You can take out all the blanks.  But you should never write anything that messy in the first place.  You should have loops iterating over the array, and your values should be array elements.

Comment: @MarcB what if `x` is `1199999999`?

Comment: hold on let me edit the text so you guys know what im trying to do...

Comment: If this code actually works, then this question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: I find it surprising that there is not `B1+B2+B3==6` rule as well

Comment: @njzk2 it is already implied by `A1+B1+C1+A2+B2+C2+A3+B3+C3==18`, although now that you mention it, **replacing** that one with a `B1+B2+B3==6` rule would clarify the if statement a bit

Comment: @njzk2 yh would clarify it tbh, but it doesn't need that rule for it to work because of A1+B1+C1+A2+B2+C2+A3+B3+C3==18

Comment: Are you simply trying to assert that every row and every column contains a 1, a 2 and a 3?

Comment: @sam: obviously I can't math good today...

Comment: @HishamMohammed: you are taking that problem by the wrong end. you are computing thousands of combinations, when you have a lot of data to simplify the initial state. A row/column can only be one of 6 combination. (apparently there are indeed 12 solutions)

Comment: One way to significantly both speed up the algo and simplify the condition would be to work in base-3 notation: use `Integer.toString(i, 3)` and have your loop bounds adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @njzk2 and everyone- guys plz. this code works 100%. can you just shorten the if statement

Comment: Then don't bother converting to integers at all.  Have a method that takes three `char`s and asserts that the set that is built from them is equal to a set that has `'1', '2', '3'` and call that method 6 times.

Comment: Your approach is *bad* all over and if your request is to make exactly the one small improvement you are looking for, this may be the wrong place to do that.

Comment: So a single square sudoku?

Comment: your output space is small enough that you might just be able to do `System.out.println("123231312");System.out.println("231123312"); etc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with others that there are many ways to simplify your code, but if you *just* want to simplify the `if` statement you can do this:

```
if (!(x.contains("6"))
     && A1*B1*C1==6 && A2*B2*C2==6 && A3*B3*C3==6
     && A1*A2*A3==6 && B1*B2*B3==6 && C1*C2*C3==6)
```

The reason this works is that the only bags of three positive integers that multiply out to 6 are `{1, 2, 3}` and `{1, 1, 6}`, so if we exclude 6 from the start, every row and column must contain 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: i dont think you've understood the task :(

Comment: @HishamMohammed  I think you are not realizing the cleverness of this solution. Just take as a for instance. Your A2 != C2 is covered by his `A2*B2*C2==6` with the providence of the first `x.contains`.

Comment: woah. yh i dismissed it too quickly. Sorry @pbabcdefp. I see how this would work :)

Comment: @HishamMohammed That's ok. It wasn't exactly clear at first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write two separate methods to help with the check.  One to check that three characters are indeed `'1', '2', 3'`, and another that accepts a `String` of 9 characters and checks the correct six subsets of the `String`.  Then you can just call that method once, in your `if` statement.

```
public static boolean is123(char first, char second, char third) {
    List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(first, second, third);
    return chars.contains('1') && chars.contains('2') && chars.contains('3');
}

public static boolean validSquare(String square) {
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        if (!is123(square.charAt(row * 3), square.charAt(row * 3 + 1), square.charAt(row * 3 + 2))) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    for (column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
        if (!is123(square.charAt(column), square.charAt(column + 3), square.charAt(column + 6))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So your `if` statement would just be `if (validSquare(String.valueOf(i)))`, if you've called your original integer `i`.  Incidentally, it would be better to use a more informative variable name in place of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your logic into a method.

```
public bool isXValid(int x)
{
    //insert logic here
}
```

then your if statement can look like this

```
if(isXValid(x))
{
    //bla bla bla
}
```

---

What's more, is that your method should better reflect what you're trying to do, and from the looks of it, you want `x` meet the following rules:

- x is a 9 digit number,
- it is a concatenation of 3 3-digit numbers,
- each 3 digit number has a `1`, a `2`, and a `3`
- no two 3 digit numbers have the same digit in the same position.

If I were to write a method to check that, I would:

1. split up my number string into the 3 digit numbers.
2. I would verify that each 3 digit number had a 1, a 2, and a 3.  If any one didn't, I would `return false`, otherwise, I'd just continue with the function.
3. I would make sure that no 2 3-digit number had the same digit in the same place.  Again, if 2 shared the same digit, I'd `return false`, otherwise I'd continue with the funciton.
4. Finally, I'd `return true` if no problems were found.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I'm not great at Java so if I did this, I would end up writing just as much code tbh. Its more the if-statement i needed help with and I think I've got my answer now :)